# Updating an XML File with FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-fake

How do I update attributes in an XML file with FAKE ?

I want to update a xml file from fake . Actually there is version_no kind of thing that are generated by teamcity , and i have to update that version no in version.config file .

I have seen that it can be done using XMLHelper class but i am not getting how to use this .

here is the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<version-info>
  <major-version number="1">
    <minor>1-aplha</minor>
    <build>123</build>
    <revision>112</revision>
  </major-version>
</version-info>
```

For example : I need to change major version , minor , build , revision  to 2 , 1 , 12 , 123 respectively .

How will I do this ??

Comment: I think I may have the first third of an answer. I hope others can then add the other two thirds :-)

As you already noticed, Fake has an [XMLHelper](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-xmlhelper.html) module with a function
`XmlPoke fileName xpath value`
with this description: "Replaces text in a XML file at the location specified by a XPath expression.".

Do you have a 'build.fsx' file already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick edit to a 'build.fsx' file of mine. The edit looks like this:

```
// Build the main module with MSBuild
Target "BuildMain" (fun _ ->
  XMLHelper.XmlPokeInnerText "./myxml.xml" "/version-info/major-version/minor" "now-beta"
  !! "./Kapoin_03_Main/Kapoin_03_Main.fsproj"
  |> MSBuild buildDir "Build" buildProps
  |> Log "Main build output: " )
```

During the build it edits 'myxml.xml' and replaces the value inside the minor tag. The edited XML then looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<version-info>
  <major-version number="1">
    <minor>now-beta</minor>
    <build>123</build>
    <revision>112</revision>
  </major-version>
</version-info>
```